# Удаление элемента из двусвязного списка

Tags: delphi, pascal, список

Пытаюсь написать процедуру удаления элемента из двусвязного списка

```
procedure TDataList.DelItem;
   var PDel: TList;
begin
   // Процедура переводит указатель на выбранный элемент
   GoToItem(FPointer);
   PDel := FItems;
   if FCount = 1 then begin
         // Если в списке 1 элемент, отчистить список полностью
         DelAll;
      end
   // Если элементов списка больше 1 и Выбран первый элемент в списке
   else if (FCount > 1) and (FPointer = 1) then begin
         // Перевод указателя на следующий элемент списка
         FItems := FItems^.PNext;
         // Удаление - Вот тут возникает ошибка, вроде что-то из памяти прочитать не может
         Dispose(PDel);
   end;
end;
```

Весь код класса:

```
unit UList;
interface
uses Messages, Dialogs, SysUtils, Classes, Grids, UStudent;

type
  TArray = array of integer;
  TData = TStudent;
  TList = ^List;
  List = record
    Data: TData;
    PNext,
    PPrev: TList;
  end;
  TDataList = class
    private
      FItems: TList;
      FCount,FPointer: Integer;
    public
      // Конструктор и деструктор
      constructor   Create(); overload;
      destructor    Destroy(); overload;
      // Процедуры
      procedure     AddItem(Key: Integer; Data: TStudent);
      procedure     DelAll();
      procedure     DelItem();
      procedure     GoToItem(Index: Integer);
      procedure     SetPointer(Index: Integer);
      procedure     Go(Key: Integer);
      // Functions
      function GetList(): TList;
      function GetCount(): Integer;
      function GetPointer(): Integer;
      property Pointer: Integer read GetPointer write SetPointer;
  end;

implementation

procedure TDataList.AddItem(Key: Integer; Data: TStudent);
var Item: TList;
begin
  FCount := FCount + 1;
  New(Item);
  Item^.Data := Data;
  // Если список пуст
  if FItems = Nil then begin
      Item^.PNext := Nil;
      Item^.PPrev := Nil;
      FItems := Item;
      FPointer := 1;
    end
  else begin
    case Key of
      // Добавление в начало списка
      1: begin
        while FItems^.PPrev <> Nil do begin
          FItems := FItems^.PPrev;
        end;
        Item^.PNext := FItems;
        Item^.PPrev := Nil;
        FItems^.PPrev := Item;
        FPointer := 1;
      end;
      // Добавление в конец списка
      2: begin
        while FItems^.PNext <> Nil do begin
          FItems := FItems^.PNext;
        end;
        Item^.PNext := Nil;
        Item^.PPrev := FItems;
        FItems^.PNext := Item;
        FPointer := FCount;
      end;
      // Добавление перед элементом
      3: begin
          if FItems^.PPrev = Nil then begin
            AddItem(1,Data);
            end
          else begin
            GoToItem(FPointer);
            Item^.PPrev := FItems^.PPrev;
            Item^.PNext := FItems;
            FItems^.PPrev := Item;
            Item^.PPrev^.PNext := Item;
          end;
      end;
      // Добавление после элемента
      4: begin
          if FPointer = FCount then begin
            AddItem(2,Data);
            end
          else begin
            GoToItem(FPointer);
            Item^.PPrev := FItems;
            Item^.PNext := FItems^.PNext;
            FItems^.PNext := Item;
            Item^.PNext^.PPrev := Item;
          end;
      end;
    end;
   end;
end;

constructor TDataList.Create;
begin
  FCount := 0;
  FPointer := 0;
  FItems := Nil;
end;

procedure TDataList.DelAll;
var PDel: TList;
begin
  Go(1);
  while FItems <> Nil do begin
    PDel := FItems;
    FItems := FITems^.PNext;
    Dispose(PDel);
  end;
  FCount := 0;
  FPointer := 0;
end;

procedure TDataList.DelItem;
var PDel: TList;
begin
  GoToItem(FPointer);

  PDel := FItems;
  // Удалить весь список если в нем всего 1 запись
  if FCount = 1 then begin
      DelAll;
    end
  // Удаление первого элемента списка
  else if (FCount > 1) and (FPointer = 1) then begin
      // Перевожу указатель на следующий элемент
      FItems := FItems^.PNext;
      FItems^.PPrev := Nil;
      Dispose(PDel);
      // FCount кол-во элементов в списке
      FCount := FCount - 1;
    end;
end;

destructor TDataList.Destroy;
begin
//
end;


function TDataList.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FCount;
end;

function TDataList.GetList: TList;
begin
  Result := FItems;
end;

function TDataList.GetPointer: Integer;
begin
  Result := FPointer;
end;

procedure TDataList.Go(Key: Integer);
begin
  case Key of
    // Go to First
    1: begin
        while FItems^.PPrev <> Nil do begin
          FItems := FItems^.PPrev;
        end;
        FPointer := 1;
    end;
    // Go to Last
    2: begin
        while FItems^.PNext <> Nil do begin
          FItems := FItems^.PNext;
        end;
        FPointer := FCount;
    end;
    // Go to Next
    3: begin
        if FItems^.PNext <> Nil then begin
          FItems := FItems^.PNext;
        end;
        FPointer := FPointer + 1;
    end;
    // Go to Prev
    4: begin
        if FItems^.PPrev <> Nil then begin
          FItems := FItems^.PPrev;
        end;
        FPointer := FPointer - 1;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TDataList.GoToItem(Index: Integer);
var I: Integer;
begin
  while FItems^.PPrev <> Nil do begin
    FItems := FItems^.PPrev;
  end;
  for I := 1 to Index - 1 do begin
    if FItems^.PNext <> Nil then FItems := FItems^.PNext;
  end;
end;

procedure TDataList.SetPointer(Index: Integer);
begin
  FPointer := Index;
end;
end.
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: "// Процедура переводит указатель на выбранный элемент" - показывайте

Comment: @Igor добавил процедуру

Comment: Попробуйте нарисовать на листочке элементы и ссылки элементов на предыдущий/следующий. Что происходит при удалении. Все ли ссылки вы перекинули прежде чем освобождать память; что будет с переменной FCount; что будет с вашим свусвязанным списком, если вы удалите последний элемент в списке, а именно что будет в переменной FItems... Хинт: на данный момент вы разрушаете список почти во всех случаях.

Comment: @YuraIvanov  Пробовал рисовать, делал все на рисунке. Там в коде видно, что я пытаюсь пока что удалить только первый элемент и по логике мне нужен указатель на первый элемент (PDel - вот), далее мне нужно перевести указатель FItems на следующий элемент дабы не пытаться удалить элемент на который сейчас указывает FItems (FItems := FItems^.PNext - вот так я это делаю). Теперь, так как у FItems есть два указателя (на след элемент и на предыдущий элемент) мне нужно избавиться от указателя на предыдущий элемент, так как предыдущий элемент сейчас будет удален и я это делаю так FItems^.PPrev := Nil.

Comment: Уже лучше. Вообще реализация списка должна содержать метод поиска элемента по номеру, для чего нужна только ссылка на первый элемент притом постоянная, а понятия текущий элемент быть не должно. И вам нет необходимости разбивать алгоритм на виды элементов (первый, последний, в середине, единственный элемент). Для удаления любого (найденного по номеру) элемента надо сцепить соседей, предварительно проверив их существование. Аналогично для добавления: будущим (найденным по номеру) соседям надо ссылки перекинуть на себя... Много лишнего, избавляйтесь.

Comment: @YuraIvanov "Уже лучше." - Все очень плохо. Смотрите дополнение к ответу.

Comment: @Igor извините, ваш ответ не является ни ответом ни конструктивной критикой. Вы констатировали факт, что все неверно, по существу если исправить все то, что вы упомянули, работать по-прежнему будет неверно. в корне.

Answer (score 1):

Вы вызываете `Dispose` подавая туда `TList`? Это неправильно. `PDel.Free;`

Или Ваши `Dispose` и `TList` не Delphi-евские?

*Update*

Теперь в вопросе не хватает того кода, в котором Вы работаете с Вашим классом `TDataList`, и при выполнении которого происходит исключение. Но дело уже не в этом. Код Ваш работать не будет, его надо переписывать.

1. Начнем с того, что человек, который называет тип элемента списка `TList` и получает в конце концов неработающий код, имеет то, что заслужил. То же самое относится к названию члена класса `FPointer`.
2. Целые числа - параметры метода `Go` - должны быть заменены на энумератор.
3. Метод `AddItem` начинает с того, что распределяет память на новый элемент, о котором благополучно забывает, когда вызывает сам себя.
4. В методе `Go` (случаи 3 и 4) Вы меняете значение `FItems`, если это возможно, однако никаких условий не проверяется при изменении значения `FPointer`.
5. Метод `GoToItem` вообще значение `FPointer` не меняет.

Вам не удалось написать код, который поддерживает `FPointer` и `FItems` в синхронизированном состоянии. Оставьте эту затею.

*И это я еще детально в коде не разбирался :).*

Comment: TList - это указатель, и судя по справочнику и примерам в процедуру Dispose нужно передавать указатель. Да и у меня процедура DelAll работает вполне нормально с использованием Dispose.

Comment: `TList` - это Ваш тип или из библиотеки? `Dispose` работает с указателем, который указывает на память распределенную вызовом `New`.

Comment: "Вот тут возникает ошибка" - какая?

Comment: Добавил скрин. Тут вроде ошибка чтения из какого-то адреса. Я проверил PDel ссылается ли на что нибудь и да ссылается. Попробовал взять данные из элемента списка PDel^.Data и все ОК. Но удалить не получается. TList - это мой тип, который TList = ^List, a List = record.... там есть код

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код, распределяющий память на элементы списка. Что ж из Вас приходится по капле информацию вытягивать!

Comment: добавил весь код класса